# How do I sum time (duration) and group by workout type in Python?

Tags: python, time, sum, duration

Here is an excerpt from my table:

| Type | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Walking | 1:33:42 |
| Running | 0:16:06 |
| Running | 0:30:24 |
| Walking | 0:50:35 |
| Running | 1:10:06 |

What i want to calculate is the duration of each workout by type.
I managed to calculate the total time using datetime.timedelta:

```
import datetime
timeList = df.Duration
mysum = datetime.timedelta()
for i in timeList:
    (h, m, s) = i.split(':')
    d = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(h), minutes=int(m), seconds=int(s))
    mysum += d
print(str(mysum))
```

But I am not sure how to use it by group. All I can think of is:

```
dfft = df.groupby(["Type"]).Duration.sum().reset_index()
```

but it returns:

| Type | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Indoor Walking | 0:46:240:10:060:29:32 |
| Outdoor Running | 0:29:140:28:280:10:580:27:420:11:330:16:060:15... |
| Outdoor Walking | 1:33:420:08:230:04:100:06:530:08:580:35:280:11... |

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we need your code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks for notifying, edited the question.

Comment: @Mykolas did the answer below resolve the question ?

Comment: @bici-sancta yes, the answer resolved the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is to make a new column that is the number of seconds (as an integer column) and then easily sum on that column in groupby ....

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type': ['W', 'R', 'R'], 'Duration' : ['1:33:42', '0:16:06', '0:30:24']}
xxx = pd.DataFrame(data = data)

sec = []
for d in xxx['Duration']:
    [h,m,s] = d.split(':')
    sec.append(int(h)*3600 + int(m)*60 + int(s))

xxx['seconds'] =  pd.Series(sec)

gb_type = xxx.groupby('Type')['seconds'].sum().reset_index()

print(gb_type)
```